# Is it possible to install windows7 or any linux to a loop file from ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, windows-7

Im just wondering is it possible to install windows7 or any linux to a loop file from ubuntu. Just reverse of what wubi offers. Loop file has to be on ext partition.

I wish to easily switch to different test os without the hassle of partitioning. Is it possible.?

Comment: not afaik without using something like bartpe which may or may not actually count as windows anyway

Comment: Please note that this question has been expanded by the OP into something that we can probably answer and which is definitely on topic. There is, or was, something called Lubi, for installing a GNU/Linux system inside another such system using principles similar to Wubi. Perhaps someone knowledgeable about that could post an answer here.

Answer (score 2):

Windows: no, Linux yes.  In the case of Ubuntu, it isn't supported by the regular installer, but you can set up the loopback mount yourself and then use `debootstrap` to initialize the system, then configure a custom grub entry to boot it with the `loop=` command line argument to point the kernel to the image file.

You may find it easier to set up a virtual machine, or [LVM](http://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm), which makes it a snap to add, remove, and resize partitions without even needing to reboot or unmount anything.